# What is difference between Thread.Join and waitHandle.WaitOne()?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Thread.Join and waitHandle.WaitOne(), both of them force the calling thread to wait. Until the thread has finished executing and until the waitHandle.Set() is called respectively.

But is there any difference between the 2 besides this?

Comment: ?? MSDN 'waitHandle.WaitOne()' says nothing about waiting until the thread has finished executing.  It's obviously a wrap of WaitForSingleObject() and and can wait on mutex, semaphore, event etc. as well as thread termination.  It's return types for its overloads are different than Join().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ...both of them force the calling thread to wait until the called
>   thread has finished executing.

No, they don't. They are completely different.

[WaitHandle.WaitOne](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.waitone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will block the calling thread until the wait handle is signaled.

[Thread.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.join%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will block the calling thread until the thread object which the `Join` method is called is finished executing(terminated)

Comment: In case of WaitHandle, after the called method has finished the task it, then the called method can signal the wait handle... which is same as what the Join does automatically. isnt it?

Comment: @helloworld Not at all. You can signal a waithandle at any time. `Thread.Join` isn't like that, it will wait till the thread is finished --it doesn't waits for a signal as opposed to waithandle.

Comment: OK but if I program my method in such a way that at the end of the method I specify WaitHandle.Set(); then does it become equivalent to a Join ? updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @helloworld Still no.You can't relate both. Meanings are different. Join says a thread is terminated, where as WaitOne says something is signaled. You could relate them by signaling them when thread exits the method, but that is not same thing.

Answer (score 1):

@helloworld, A distinction is "at the end of the method". Unless your method catches all exceptions, it may exit due to unhandled exception (e.g. due to thread.abort), before your call to WaitHandle.Set().

WaitHandles require cooperation/knowledge between threads. The called thread has to be passed the wait handle, and it has to signal at the appropriate time. It is useful, when two threads are sharing a resource such as a pub-sub queue.

WaitHandles are just one of many signaling/locking mechanisms. Semaphores, mutexes, lock files and even thread-shared variables (accessed carefully, e.g. Interlocked.Increment) can be used for signaling.

Thread.Join - does not require any cooperation from the called thread. When the called thread is done for any reason, including abnormal termination, join returns.

Thread.Join is more like Process.Wait. Process.Wait returns when the process terminates for any reason.

In short, if you need to know when a thread terminates for any reason, use Thread.Join.

When you need to know if a thread has executed to a certain point, use signaling.